# Google Maps Onload Callback -Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm struggling with adding Google Maps JS API to my Angular project.

In `index.htm` I have:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"
        async defer></script>
```

In my component, how is it possible to know that the `maps api` is fully loaded and available?

To be clear, for example, in Google Charts API, we can call:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback();
```

to initiate other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the onload event in you script tag:

#### example(https://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/BJmOxB?editors=1112):

```
<script>
  function jsFileLoaded() {
    console.log('file loaded!');
  }
</script>
<script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" onload="jsFileLoaded()" async defer></script>
```

Comment: But how can I get notified in my component?

Comment: You could use an event emitter, what version of angular are you using?

Comment: Event Emitter from `index.html`? Angular v5